# Unoconv LibreOffice Pdf Preview is generating a blank pdf

Tags: php, pdf, libreoffice, unoconv

I am using below configuration

- Ubuntu 16.04
- LibreOffice 5.1.6.2
- Unoconv 0.7

I am trying to generate preview of a pdf file using below command

```
sudo unoconv  -e PageRange=1-3 -f pdf --output abc-preview.pdf Numberic.pdf
```

I have also try to install fonts like below

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-crosextra-caladea
```

**but it is generating blank pdf**

original file is [here](http://test.66watts.com/download/Numeric.pdf)

converted file is [here](http://test.66watts.com/download/abc-preview.pdf)

Please help me its been 2 week, I am not able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That pdf starts at page 207, so it looks a bit queer, try another approach if you're desperate.    [image]
Install `qpdf` using synaptic or apt, then:

```
qpdf --empty --pages Numeric.pdf 1-3 -- N1.pdf
```

Edit:
To convert a .doc or .docx file to pdf

```
lowriter --convert-to pdf yourfilename.xxx
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but is it really going to work, I mean if got any problem in qpdf and where should I go. I think there their must be a solution for libre office if I not able to find then I will go with your solution.

Comment: I take a pragmatic approach to these things. That file, as far as libreoffice is concerned, is corrupt, so think of my solution as just another string to your bow. As far as problems with qpdf, it's just another piece of software, just like libreoffice, source code and issues are on github. Source downloads https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/ but as I said it is in the repositories on your box and finally let's face it, you didn't get anywhere in 2 weeks waiting for a libreoffice solution but that said one may come along. It depends on how long you are prepared to wait :)

Comment: thank you @RolfOfSaxony. This work very well for me but can you suggest for doc,docx to pdf conversion. I am really very sorry i didn't mention that i also need doc,docx to pdf conversion. Please help!

Comment: As you suggest, I have tested soffice, lowriter but they are not able to convert hindi document and they are not throwing any errors. I am attaching document in my question n thanks for your valuable time. thank you bro.

Comment: here is the link to download https://www.drawnear.club/public/images/hindi_doc.docx

Comment: This rabbit hole just gets deeper and deeper, doesn't it. Unless your machine has `Hindi` loaded for the pdf reader, Libreoffice, etc I doubt that it will work. See : https://oppili.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/enabling-tamil-in-libreoffice/ for some clues or ask a new question specifically about converting Hindi documents.